# Trouble styling TD elements from external stylesheet

Tags: css

I'm trying to port code over from using inline css to using a stylesheet and as I'm pretty much a total css noob I'm having trouble.

Most of the things I've moved over to external have worked fine, but I can't seem to get TD elements to use styles defined in the stylesheet. Here's an example:

```
<td class="text_right">...</td>
```

```
.text_right {
text-align: right;
}
```

Why doesn't that work?

Comment: Silly question but you are including your external stylesheet through a `<link>` tag, right?

Comment: @ChrisHayes - yep, and the style works with other elements.

Comment: Duh, I didn't read your question close enough. Whoops. Do you have a JSFiddle or a webpage you could link to? Perhaps the style is being overridden somewhere, or some other odd behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work, however bear in mind that your `<td>` element should have some dimensions, otherwise it will be as wide as the content.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JGMck/5/) for a demo

Answer (score 1):

```
<td class="text_right"><a>...</a></td>    

.text_right {
text-align: right;
width: 300px;
}
```

that should work , put you text in `<a>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Try using !important . Like this ;

```
.text_right {
text-align: right !important;
}
```

if you still see it not aligned please check css for that element overridden rules (with chrome or opera) by right click and investigate